Is there a way I can get an android push notification on my Windows VM?
I have a specific workflow to run when I get a push notification from an application (I do not own this application). Right now, I use macrodriod on my phone to make a API call to a free endpoint I have on Render which sends a message using websockets to my VM listening on the other end (I don't have a public IP). Is there a way I can make this flow easier? It is very time sensitive and I need it to start the workflow as soon as possible.
Is there any way I can get the push notification directly to my VM using some kind of FCM creds I can get from the application? My VM does not have a GPU and cannot run Emulators. Would like to not take on/minimize any additional costs (public IPs, GPU VMs etc)
Had tried looking up if there's any way to get creds from the application but so far no luck. I don't have much experience in Android development/push notifications

Firebase Cloud Messaging only supports delivering messages to Android, iOS and web clients. It does not support delivery to native Windows apps.
Also see:

I need to use Firebase Cloud Messaging on a DESKTOP unity application
Using Firesharp for Windows desktop push notifications only
How to receive push notifications from Firebase cloud messaging on Windows
Use Firebase Cloud Messaging in a Flutter Windows app


this question is very opinion-based, but my idea for shorter way would be to install adb on VM and sniff logs... install/create an app, which will put some "special" log when detect notification (e.g. parse texts and make a json), on VM make some script-on-adb checking every line, pick those from your app and read data
note you can connect to adb through usb or wifi (same network, tcp)
there is no way for re-directing notification from app to anywhere else (if you are not author/owner) without 3rd-party apps
